# iPhone Crash Logs Don't Symbolicate Correctly and are Double Spaced

Tags: ios, xcode4, crash-reports

This is odd, and is only happening with one application that Im developing. Im using XCode 4.0 and other apps do symbolicate correctly for me. It happens when I receive crash logs from multiple testers, on multiple devices (iPhones + iPads) so is not specific to a particular person.

The app has a lite and a pro target, and is a universal app which runs on iPhones and iPads if that makes a difference.

The crash logs load initially and look like a regular crash log, but as soon as they are 'processed', they are not symbolicated and end up being double spaced so they look like this:

```
I n c i d e n t   I d e n t i f i e r :   8 0 D 0 B E 6 A - 5 A C 8 - 4 E 8 A - B D 4 2 - 9 4 2 8 A 0 6 4 A 2 3 D 
C r a s h R e p o r t e r   K e y :       4 2 b 2 b e f 9 1 4 e 4 2 b a c a b f 1 2 6 4 1 9 1 5 8 3 2 7 5 3 e a f 9 f f d 
H a r d w a r e   M o d e l :             i P h o n e 1 , 2 
P r o c e s s :                   A P P N A M E  [ 3 5 9 ] 
P a t h :                         / v a r / m o b i l e / A p p l i c a t i o n s / 2 5 E E B E F 1 - 8 8 1 7 - 4 1 3 8 - A 5 B F - D D E B 7 B D E C 2 E 2 / A P P N A M E. a p p / A P P N A M E
I d e n t i f i e r :             A P P N A M E
V e r s i o n :                   ? ? ?   ( ? ? ? ) 
C o d e   T y p e :               A R M   ( N a t i v e ) 
P a r e n t   P r o c e s s :     l a u n c h d   [ 1 ] 

D a t e / T i m e :               2 0 1 1 - 0 6 - 1 0   2 1 : 0 6 : 3 5 . 3 9 5   - 0 4 0 0 
O S   V e r s i o n :             i P h o n e   O S   4 . 2 . 1   ( 8 C 1 4 8 ) 
R e p o r t   V e r s i o n :     1 0 4 

E x c e p t i o n   T y p e :     E X C _ B A D _ A C C E S S   ( S I G B U S ) 
E x c e p t i o n   C o d e s :   K E R N _ P R O T E C T I O N _ F A I L U R E   a t   0 x 0 0 0 8 7 3 6 0 
C r a s h e d   T h r e a d :     0 

T h r e a d   0   C r a s h e d : 
0       ? ? ?                                                            0 x 0 0 0 8 7 3 6 0   0   +   5 5 3 8 2 4 
1       ? ? ?                                                            0 x f f f f f f f 8   0   +   - 8 

T h r e a d   1 : 
0       l i b S y s t e m . B . d y l i b                                0 x 3 5 d 8 f 9 7 4   0 x 3 5 d 5 a 0 0 0   +   2 1 9 5 0 8 
1       l i b S y s t e m . B . d y l i b                                0 x 3 5 e 5 e 2 f c   0 x 3 5 d 5 a 0 0 0   +   1 0 6 5 7 2 4 
2       l i b S y s t e m . B . d y l i b                                0 x 3 5 e 5 d d 6 8   0 x 3 5 d 5 a 0 0 0   +   1 0 6 4 2 9 6 
3       l i b S y s t e m . B . d y l i b                                0 x 3 5 e 5 d 7 8 8   0 x 3 5 d 5 a 0 0 0   +   1 0 6 2 7 9 2 
4       l i b S y s t e m . B . d y l i b                                0 x 3 5 d e 6 9 7 0   0 x 3 5 d 5 a 0 0 0   +   5 7 5 8 5 6 
5       l i b S y s t e m . B . d y l i b                                0 x 3 5 d d d 2 f c   0 x 3 5 d 5 a 0 0 0   +   5 3 7 3 4 0 

T h r e a d   2 : 
0       l i b S y s t e m . B . d y l i b                                0 x 3 5 d 5 b 3 b 0   0 x 3 5 d 5 a 0 0 0   +   5 0 4 0 
1       l i b S y s t e m . B . d y l i b                                0 x 3 5 d 5 d 8 9 4   0 x 3 5 d 5 a 0 0 0   +   1 4 4 8 4 
2       C o r e F o u n d a t i o n                                      0 x 3 7 5 2 1 f 7 c   0 x 3 7 4 f 9 0 0 0   +   1 6 7 8 0 4 
3       C o r e F o u n d a t i o n                                      0 x 3 7 5 2 1 7 8 0   0 x 3 7 4 f 9 0 0 0   +   1 6 5 7 6 0 
4       C o r e F o u n d a t i o n                                      0 x 3 7 5 2 1 5 0 4   0 x 3 7 4 f 9 0 0 0   +   1 6 5 1 2 4 
5       C o r e F o u n d a t i o n                                      0 x 3 7 5 2 1 4 1 2   0 x 3 7 4 f 9 0 0 0   +   1 6 4 8 8 2 
6       W e b C o r e                                                    0 x 3 3 1 8 b d 1 4   0 x 3 3 0 7 0 0 0 0   +   1 1 6 2 5 1 6 
7       l i b S y s t e m . B . d y l i b                                0 x 3 5 d e 5 b 4 4   0 x 3 5 d 5 a 0 0 0   +   5 7 2 2 2 8 
8       l i b S y s t e m . B . d y l i b                                0 x 3 5 d d 7 7 a 4   0 x 3 5 d 5 a 0 0 0   +   5 1 3 9 5 6 

T h r e a d   3 : 
0       l i b S y s t e m . B . d y l i b                                0 x 3 5 d 8 4 8 d 8   0 x 3 5 d 5 a 0 0 0   +   1 7 4 2 9 6 
1       C o r e F o u n d a t i o n                                      0 x 3 7 5 5 a a 3 4   0 x 3 7 4 f 9 0 0 0   +   3 9 9 9 2 4 
2       l i b S y s t e m . B . d y l i b                                0 x 3 5 d e 5 b 4 4   0 x 3 5 d 5 a 0 0 0   +   5 7 2 2 2 8 
3       l i b S y s t e m . B . d y l i b                                0 x 3 5 d d 7 7 a 4   0 x 3 5 d 5 a 0 0 0   +   5 1 3 9 5 6 

T h r e a d   0   c r a s h e d   w i t h   A R M   T h r e a d   S t a t e : 
        r 0 :   0 x 0 0 1 2 b 8 a 0         r 1 :   0 x 3 5 d 0 f 4 a 7             r 2 :   0 x 0 0 1 a 0 d 0 0             r 3 :   0 x 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
        r 4 :   0 x 0 0 1 2 b 8 a 0         r 5 :   0 x 3 e 7 4 0 6 2 8             r 6 :   0 x 0 0 1 4 4 1 0 0             r 7 :   0 x 0 0 1 7 6 1 4 0 
        r 8 :   0 x 3 5 c e f 5 7 7         r 9 :   0 x 3 e 6 e 5 9 e 8           r 1 0 :   0 x 0 0 1 8 a 5 c 0           r 1 1 :   0 x 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
        i p :   0 x 3 5 9 8 6 8 a 4         s p :   0 x 2 f d f e 4 f 8             l r :   0 x 3 5 9 8 6 9 8 c             p c :   0 x 0 0 0 8 7 3 6 0 
    c p s r :   0 x 6 0 0 f 0 0 1 0 

B i n a r y   I m a g e s : 
        0 x 1 0 0 0   -         0 x 7 6 f f f   + A P P N A M E  a r m v 6     < 8 d c d 8 3 e f b 6 7 9 3 1 e 3 9 5 d e 0 1 c 5 1 b f 5 b e 7 c >   / v a r / m o b i l e / A p p l i c a t i o n s / 2 5 E E B E F 1 - 8 8 1 7 - 4 1 3 8 - A 5 B F - D D E B 7 B D E C 2 E 2 / A P P N A M E. a p p / A P P N A M E
      0 x e d 0 0 0   -         0 x e e f f f     d n s . s o   a r m v 6     < 8 8 b 5 6 9 3 1 1 c c a 4 a 9 5 9 3 b 2 d 6 7 0 0 5 1 8 6 0 d 1 >   / u s r / l i b / i n f o / d n s . s o 
0 x 2 f e 0 0 0 0 0   -   0 x 2 f e 2 9 f f f     d y l d   a r m v 6     < 6 1 7 f 6 d a f 4 1 0 3 5 4 7 c 4 7 a 8 4 0 7 a 2 e 0 b 9 0 d e >   / u s r / l i b / d y l d 
0 x 3 0 2 7 0 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 0 2 7 b f f f     I T S y n c   a r m v 6     < a 4 5 1 2 0 5 e 8 9 3 7 3 c b d f 0 8 3 2 6 8 8 0 8 5 e 8 f 7 2 >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / P r i v a t e F r a m e w o r k s / I T S y n c . f r a m e w o r k / I T S y n c 
0 x 3 0 2 7 c 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 0 2 7 e f f f     I O M o b i l e F r a m e b u f f e r   a r m v 6     < f 4 2 b b b f 6 7 1 9 5 a 7 b 9 8 d 6 7 a d 0 2 1 b b a 4 7 8 4 >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / P r i v a t e F r a m e w o r k s / I O M o b i l e F r a m e b u f f e r . f r a m e w o r k / I O M o b i l e F r a m e b u f f e r 
0 x 3 0 2 7 f 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 0 3 8 d f f f     C F N e t w o r k   a r m v 6     < d 6 e e e e 8 3 2 1 6 e e 9 c 5 5 3 1 3 4 f 0 6 9 f 3 7 c b c 2 >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / F r a m e w o r k s / C F N e t w o r k . f r a m e w o r k / C F N e t w o r k 
0 x 3 0 3 e f 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 0 3 f 4 f f f     C a p t i v e N e t w o r k   a r m v 6     < f 4 1 d f 4 b 3 5 8 b 7 7 b 2 9 f f 8 5 e 0 e a e a 8 8 e e 1 d >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / P r i v a t e F r a m e w o r k s / C a p t i v e N e t w o r k . f r a m e w o r k / C a p t i v e N e t w o r k 
0 x 3 0 3 f 5 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 0 4 4 4 f f f     S e c u r i t y   a r m v 6     < c f 6 2 5 b 4 d c 7 e a 9 2 8 8 9 1 3 1 3 4 4 4 e f 6 4 a 7 c b >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / F r a m e w o r k s / S e c u r i t y . f r a m e w o r k / S e c u r i t y 
0 x 3 0 4 4 5 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 0 5 5 c f f f     l i b i c u c o r e . A . d y l i b   a r m v 6     < 8 9 6 8 f f 3 f 6 2 d 7 7 8 0 b b 1 b d 7 5 0 2 6 a 7 6 2 8 d 0 >   / u s r / l i b / l i b i c u c o r e . A . d y l i b 
0 x 3 0 5 5 d 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 0 5 6 1 f f f     A p p l e P u s h S e r v i c e   a r m v 6     < 0 5 6 0 b 6 3 0 d 2 6 e 2 6 1 e 2 0 5 f c 5 8 9 4 2 e 1 8 8 5 c >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / P r i v a t e F r a m e w o r k s / A p p l e P u s h S e r v i c e . f r a m e w o r k / A p p l e P u s h S e r v i c e 
0 x 3 0 5 9 d 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 0 5 a 8 f f f     M o b i l e W i F i   a r m v 6     < c 7 5 3 2 e 6 3 e 0 8 3 a 1 d d 2 a 0 e f 7 3 5 2 b 8 5 7 4 9 d >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / P r i v a t e F r a m e w o r k s / M o b i l e W i F i . f r a m e w o r k / M o b i l e W i F i 
0 x 3 0 5 a a 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 0 6 1 2 f f f     l i b v D S P . d y l i b   a r m v 6     < 9 d 2 6 4 7 3 3 f c 6 7 5 9 4 3 c 0 8 2 b d 3 b 9 b 5 6 7 b 5 9 >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / F r a m e w o r k s / A c c e l e r a t e . f r a m e w o r k / F r a m e w o r k s / v e c L i b . f r a m e w o r k / l i b v D S P . d y l i b 
0 x 3 0 6 1 3 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 0 6 4 d f f f     M o b i l e C o r e S e r v i c e s   a r m v 6     < b e b 4 7 3 c e 8 0 3 9 0 5 5 4 b b 4 a f 2 1 5 5 4 5 2 2 2 8 6 >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / F r a m e w o r k s / M o b i l e C o r e S e r v i c e s . f r a m e w o r k / M o b i l e C o r e S e r v i c e s 
0 x 3 0 6 5 c 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 0 6 6 e f f f     l i b b s m . 0 . d y l i b   a r m v 6     < 5 1 e 7 b b 1 8 d a 9 a f a 4 4 a 3 3 e 5 4 e 4 2 f b d 0 7 0 7 >   / u s r / l i b / l i b b s m . 0 . d y l i b 
0 x 3 0 6 6 f 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 0 6 c 6 f f f     C o r e M e d i a   a r m v 6     < c d 5 e 9 3 9 8 c 1 6 1 f 1 2 9 1 4 6 9 3 1 e 8 8 8 e 1 c 9 2 e >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / F r a m e w o r k s / C o r e M e d i a . f r a m e w o r k / C o r e M e d i a 
0 x 3 0 6 f 0 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 0 6 f e f f f     l i b z . 1 . d y l i b   a r m v 6     < 8 4 5 9 2 e 9 6 b a e 1 a 6 6 1 3 7 4 b 0 f 9 a 5 d 0 3 a 3 a 0 >   / u s r / l i b / l i b z . 1 . d y l i b 
0 x 3 0 6 f f 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 0 7 2 9 f f f     P r i n t K i t   a r m v 6     < 7 4 f 9 7 1 0 f a 0 1 a 3 3 b 5 b b 0 4 c 4 a e a b d 6 b e 7 d >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / P r i v a t e F r a m e w o r k s / P r i n t K i t . f r a m e w o r k / P r i n t K i t 
0 x 3 0 7 d 7 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 0 8 2 a f f f     I O K i t   a r m v 6     < 2 0 d a 5 e 8 2 2 f 2 1 a 8 d 0 a 7 c 5 b 3 e 1 4 9 3 3 0 e f d >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / F r a m e w o r k s / I O K i t . f r a m e w o r k / V e r s i o n s / A / I O K i t 
0 x 3 0 8 3 1 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 0 8 3 b f f f     A c c o u n t S e t t i n g s   a r m v 6     < e c a 6 7 a b 0 4 f 7 2 4 e 1 f a 7 c 6 4 0 6 c 8 8 e 7 5 4 3 3 >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / P r i v a t e F r a m e w o r k s / A c c o u n t S e t t i n g s . f r a m e w o r k / A c c o u n t S e t t i n g s 
0 x 3 0 9 9 9 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 0 9 c 5 f f f     D a t a A c c e s s   a r m v 6     < 8 c 0 4 5 8 2 2 d 5 7 a 3 6 9 8 3 5 f 5 b 4 0 6 5 3 a 4 8 8 3 8 >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / P r i v a t e F r a m e w o r k s / D a t a A c c e s s . f r a m e w o r k / D a t a A c c e s s 
0 x 3 0 9 c 6 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 0 9 f 4 f f f     M I M E   a r m v 6     < f a c 8 f 5 5 c 5 0 8 f f 4 7 6 e 0 7 8 9 4 a f 7 a b d b 7 6 1 >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / P r i v a t e F r a m e w o r k s / M I M E . f r a m e w o r k / M I M E 
0 x 3 0 a 0 4 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 0 a a 3 f f f     P r o o f R e a d e r   a r m v 6     < 2 7 3 4 9 2 0 b 6 2 f 1 7 4 c 1 7 a e e b 1 5 f 3 7 1 6 1 5 e f >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / P r i v a t e F r a m e w o r k s / P r o o f R e a d e r . f r a m e w o r k / P r o o f R e a d e r 
0 x 3 0 a d 6 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 0 b 1 a f f f     A d d r e s s B o o k   a r m v 6     < 1 f 3 0 c 3 3 7 0 d a d 2 7 3 3 1 a 4 9 1 b a 4 b 1 9 0 8 1 3 c >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / F r a m e w o r k s / A d d r e s s B o o k . f r a m e w o r k / A d d r e s s B o o k 
0 x 3 0 b 3 d 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 0 b 9 c f f f     C o r e A u d i o   a r m v 6     < c c c 4 b a c e 0 d 6 e c a 7 9 a 3 2 e d 8 4 d 5 6 6 f 7 2 e 9 >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / F r a m e w o r k s / C o r e A u d i o . f r a m e w o r k / C o r e A u d i o 
0 x 3 2 d 7 d 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 2 d 8 9 f f f     l i b k x l d . d y l i b   a r m v 6     < f 7 4 f 3 5 9 d e 7 b b e 3 c c d c 3 7 f a 6 f 3 3 2 a e b f 4 >   / u s r / l i b / s y s t e m / l i b k x l d . d y l i b 
0 x 3 2 d 9 5 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 2 e 5 c f f f     l i b o b j c . A . d y l i b   a r m v 6     < 4 2 9 8 4 1 2 6 9 f 8 b c e c d 4 b a 3 2 6 4 a 8 7 2 5 d a d 6 >   / u s r / l i b / l i b o b j c . A . d y l i b 
0 x 3 2 e 5 d 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 2 e c d f f f     l i b s q l i t e 3 . d y l i b   a r m v 6     < 8 7 b 9 b b 4 7 6 8 7 9 0 2 d 9 1 2 0 d 0 3 d 1 d a 9 e b 9 f c >   / u s r / l i b / l i b s q l i t e 3 . d y l i b 
0 x 3 2 f 0 c 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 2 f 1 f f f f     l i b m i s . d y l i b   a r m v 6     < d b a 9 c 0 8 6 b 4 9 b d 9 5 4 0 9 3 0 f f 2 7 2 1 1 5 7 0 d 6 >   / u s r / l i b / l i b m i s . d y l i b 
0 x 3 3 0 5 5 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 3 0 6 1 f f f     S p r i n g B o a r d S e r v i c e s   a r m v 6     < f d 0 c 4 7 2 4 3 6 b 3 3 0 6 f 5 b 5 6 1 1 8 c 9 3 c 8 a 4 2 3 >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / P r i v a t e F r a m e w o r k s / S p r i n g B o a r d S e r v i c e s . f r a m e w o r k / S p r i n g B o a r d S e r v i c e s 
0 x 3 3 0 6 2 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 3 0 6 f f f f     M o b i l e B l u e t o o t h   a r m v 6     < 2 b 6 8 5 1 6 e 1 3 2 1 0 1 1 a 4 e f b e e 2 9 4 7 d 4 6 3 c 6 >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / P r i v a t e F r a m e w o r k s / M o b i l e B l u e t o o t h . f r a m e w o r k / M o b i l e B l u e t o o t h 
0 x 3 3 0 7 0 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 3 8 b f f f f     W e b C o r e   a r m v 6     < a a 3 b 6 8 2 7 f 0 5 1 d a 7 a 3 4 9 4 c 9 b e e 4 e b e 2 9 0 >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / P r i v a t e F r a m e w o r k s / W e b C o r e . f r a m e w o r k / W e b C o r e 
0 x 3 3 8 c 0 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 3 8 d 4 f f f     M o b i l e D e v i c e L i n k   a r m v 6     < 1 9 d 6 6 0 7 8 f 8 c f 1 9 b e 5 5 8 7 1 3 c 1 3 6 1 2 c 7 a 3 >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / P r i v a t e F r a m e w o r k s / M o b i l e D e v i c e L i n k . f r a m e w o r k / M o b i l e D e v i c e L i n k 
0 x 3 3 a 6 b 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 3 a b 3 f f f     i C a l e n d a r   a r m v 6     < f b b 7 1 7 8 7 4 e a 0 e d e 2 4 4 5 4 a 5 d e f 6 4 4 a b 6 9 >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / P r i v a t e F r a m e w o r k s / i C a l e n d a r . f r a m e w o r k / i C a l e n d a r 
0 x 3 3 a b 4 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 3 a b 4 f f f     A c c e l e r a t e   a r m v 6     < c d d e 2 4 a 7 a d 0 0 4 b 2 b 2 e 6 0 0 c d 4 f 3 a c 5 e b 7 >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / F r a m e w o r k s / A c c e l e r a t e . f r a m e w o r k / A c c e l e r a t e 
0 x 3 3 b 3 2 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 3 b 7 2 f f f     Q u i c k L o o k   a r m v 6     < 5 4 4 0 0 e 0 d 4 8 e c 8 6 c 8 4 e 9 3 7 e 5 5 7 9 0 b 9 e 5 4 >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / F r a m e w o r k s / Q u i c k L o o k . f r a m e w o r k / Q u i c k L o o k 
0 x 3 3 b b c 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 3 c 0 a f f f     C o r e T e x t   a r m v 6     < 1 6 c 9 5 8 2 f d f f b 5 9 8 1 7 8 2 8 7 c 6 c e 9 f d 6 8 9 7 >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / F r a m e w o r k s / C o r e T e x t . f r a m e w o r k / C o r e T e x t 
0 x 3 3 c 1 6 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 3 d 7 3 f f f     l i b G L P r o g r a m m a b i l i t y . d y l i b   a r m v 6     < a e c 6 b 5 4 f f d 5 3 2 b b 6 0 7 a a b 4 a c b a b 6 7 9 b 6 >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / F r a m e w o r k s / O p e n G L E S . f r a m e w o r k / l i b G L P r o g r a m m a b i l i t y . d y l i b 
0 x 3 3 d 7 6 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 3 d 7 9 f f f     A c t o r K i t   a r m v 6     < d 3 e c 5 0 b 4 a 7 f 0 2 5 7 e f 3 1 b a f 3 7 9 3 6 d c 2 7 5 >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / P r i v a t e F r a m e w o r k s / A c t o r K i t . f r a m e w o r k / A c t o r K i t 
0 x 3 3 d 8 5 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 3 e 7 1 f f f     Q u a r t z C o r e   a r m v 6     < 7 7 c d 9 1 f f 2 1 f e 6 c 5 8 c 3 0 9 f 2 c 8 2 e b 9 5 c a 5 >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / F r a m e w o r k s / Q u a r t z C o r e . f r a m e w o r k / Q u a r t z C o r e 
0 x 3 3 e 7 2 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 3 e 8 1 f f f     G r a p h i c s S e r v i c e s   a r m v 6     < a f 2 0 a b a 0 e c 9 6 e 7 b 7 c 4 2 b b 5 5 a c 7 6 3 c 7 8 4 >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / P r i v a t e F r a m e w o r k s / G r a p h i c s S e r v i c e s . f r a m e w o r k / G r a p h i c s S e r v i c e s 
0 x 3 3 e a d 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 3 f 6 e f f f     I m a g e I O   a r m v 6     < 0 c 1 b 6 f 4 6 6 6 6 7 f f 3 4 5 f 2 3 9 9 d 8 1 4 2 a 9 d 1 0 >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / F r a m e w o r k s / I m a g e I O . f r a m e w o r k / I m a g e I O 
0 x 3 3 f 7 8 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 3 f 7 9 f f f     C o r e S u r f a c e   a r m v 6     < 5 e 2 9 0 5 1 4 3 8 0 c 6 2 6 e 9 b 0 f 9 f 9 9 8 5 b 9 d c 7 a >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / P r i v a t e F r a m e w o r k s / C o r e S u r f a c e . f r a m e w o r k / C o r e S u r f a c e 
0 x 3 4 0 a c 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 4 0 b f f f f     N o t e s   a r m v 6     < a c f 9 e 5 4 8 9 4 8 e c b 2 9 9 2 7 0 c 8 3 9 8 e f 2 9 7 a 1 >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / P r i v a t e F r a m e w o r k s / N o t e s . f r a m e w o r k / N o t e s 
0 x 3 4 1 3 7 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 4 1 5 6 f f f     E A P 8 0 2 1 X   a r m v 6     < f a 5 6 8 4 5 b 5 3 9 6 c 3 e b b 3 6 8 c 2 3 6 8 3 3 1 6 4 3 c >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / P r i v a t e F r a m e w o r k s / E A P 8 0 2 1 X . f r a m e w o r k / E A P 8 0 2 1 X 
0 x 3 4 1 a d 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 4 1 e b f f f     C o n t e n t I n d e x   a r m v 6     < 7 f 3 3 3 4 3 8 0 a c c 7 2 2 9 2 5 7 1 8 0 3 f 0 b 4 9 0 1 8 9 >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / P r i v a t e F r a m e w o r k s / C o n t e n t I n d e x . f r a m e w o r k / C o n t e n t I n d e x 
0 x 3 4 3 a 0 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 4 3 b f f f f     B o m   a r m v 6     < f 4 1 b e f 8 1 e 2 3 e 2 b f f 5 9 1 5 5 e 5 c e 4 6 7 6 2 d 3 >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / P r i v a t e F r a m e w o r k s / B o m . f r a m e w o r k / B o m 
0 x 3 4 3 c 0 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 4 4 b d f f f     J a v a S c r i p t C o r e   a r m v 6     < 3 5 4 7 c 9 2 c 1 e f c 0 5 2 2 b 0 8 7 e 7 f 1 0 e b a 7 7 2 8 >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / P r i v a t e F r a m e w o r k s / J a v a S c r i p t C o r e . f r a m e w o r k / J a v a S c r i p t C o r e 
0 x 3 4 4 b e 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 4 5 0 0 f f f     M a n a g e d C o n f i g u r a t i o n   a r m v 6     < 3 9 7 7 2 3 a 3 3 c 1 9 c 3 4 8 7 d 3 0 4 d 6 9 5 8 0 a c b f c >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / P r i v a t e F r a m e w o r k s / M a n a g e d C o n f i g u r a t i o n . f r a m e w o r k / M a n a g e d C o n f i g u r a t i o n 
0 x 3 4 9 5 4 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 4 a 5 c f f f     C o r e D a t a   a r m v 6     < 6 e 3 a f 4 b 4 6 4 8 a e 6 9 5 f 8 d 4 b c 0 b f 5 a 9 d b a 5 >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / F r a m e w o r k s / C o r e D a t a . f r a m e w o r k / C o r e D a t a 
0 x 3 4 a 6 e 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 4 a 7 2 f f f     C e r t U I   a r m v 6     < 5 7 c 4 9 9 b a f 9 d 3 4 3 a 7 8 f e 1 b 4 3 f 0 f 3 e f 9 9 7 >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / P r i v a t e F r a m e w o r k s / C e r t U I . f r a m e w o r k / C e r t U I 
0 x 3 4 b 5 2 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 4 f 1 f f f f     l i b L A P A C K . d y l i b   a r m v 6     < 0 e b 7 3 4 c 9 1 1 6 5 4 1 6 2 2 4 b 9 8 c 9 4 3 f f 6 4 7 6 b >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / F r a m e w o r k s / A c c e l e r a t e . f r a m e w o r k / F r a m e w o r k s / v e c L i b . f r a m e w o r k / l i b L A P A C K . d y l i b 
0 x 3 4 f 2 0 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 5 0 1 4 f f f     l i b i c o n v . 2 . d y l i b   a r m v 6     < 0 1 9 1 6 d 6 7 8 4 f 4 d e 8 f 3 7 4 6 9 7 8 f a a e 9 c 5 f a >   / u s r / l i b / l i b i c o n v . 2 . d y l i b 
0 x 3 5 0 1 5 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 5 0 2 2 f f f     C o r e V i d e o   a r m v 6     < 7 b 1 0 0 f d 5 f d f 9 8 d b 1 c d 0 f 0 6 4 9 e 7 f 6 f 3 1 6 >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / F r a m e w o r k s / C o r e V i d e o . f r a m e w o r k / C o r e V i d e o 
0 x 3 5 0 2 3 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 5 0 7 d f f f     M e s s a g e U I   a r m v 6     < 2 1 b b 9 d 9 3 9 1 1 f 7 0 1 5 b 7 9 a e f 9 d c 6 d f 5 5 e f >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / F r a m e w o r k s / M e s s a g e U I . f r a m e w o r k / M e s s a g e U I 
0 x 3 5 0 8 7 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 5 1 4 8 f f f     A d d r e s s B o o k U I   a r m v 6     < f e a 7 2 7 3 2 4 5 1 6 1 0 2 7 7 e 2 2 a 6 6 7 d 3 5 a d 7 6 d >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / F r a m e w o r k s / A d d r e s s B o o k U I . f r a m e w o r k / A d d r e s s B o o k U I 
0 x 3 5 1 5 1 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 5 2 7 2 f f f     F o u n d a t i o n   a r m v 6     < 6 b d e b 1 9 a 1 f c b 9 3 e 2 9 3 0 d a d b 5 0 4 1 6 f 8 8 1 >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / F r a m e w o r k s / F o u n d a t i o n . f r a m e w o r k / F o u n d a t i o n 
0 x 3 5 2 9 b 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 5 2 a 6 f f f     l i b b z 2 . 1 . 0 . d y l i b   a r m v 6     < 6 a a 8 a 4 e d 0 9 0 6 a 4 9 5 d 0 5 9 a c e 9 1 2 5 f 5 2 5 d >   / u s r / l i b / l i b b z 2 . 1 . 0 . d y l i b 
0 x 3 5 2 d c 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 5 3 4 2 f f f     l i b B L A S . d y l i b   a r m v 6     < 1 1 a 3 6 7 7 a 0 8 1 7 5 a 3 0 d f 1 b 3 d 6 6 d 7 e 0 9 5 1 a >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / F r a m e w o r k s / A c c e l e r a t e . f r a m e w o r k / F r a m e w o r k s / v e c L i b . f r a m e w o r k / l i b B L A S . d y l i b 
0 x 3 5 4 0 6 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 5 4 0 6 f f f     v e c L i b   a r m v 6     < 8 f 9 1 4 b 3 e 8 a 5 8 1 d 4 9 f b 2 1 d 2 c 0 f f 7 5 b e 0 3 >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / F r a m e w o r k s / A c c e l e r a t e . f r a m e w o r k / F r a m e w o r k s / v e c L i b . f r a m e w o r k / v e c L i b 
0 x 3 5 4 0 7 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 5 4 0 a f f f     M o b i l e I n s t a l l a t i o n   a r m v 6     < 4 5 6 e d 7 f e 6 d d 9 f c d 8 e 7 8 d f 4 2 5 0 8 5 b 1 4 5 2 >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / P r i v a t e F r a m e w o r k s / M o b i l e I n s t a l l a t i o n . f r a m e w o r k / M o b i l e I n s t a l l a t i o n 
0 x 3 5 5 4 1 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 5 5 4 7 f f f     M B X 2 D   a r m v 6     < f a d 4 9 5 5 c a b 3 6 e 0 1 7 9 d f 6 f 8 f 2 7 d 3 6 5 b 8 f >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / P r i v a t e F r a m e w o r k s / M B X 2 D . f r a m e w o r k / M B X 2 D 
0 x 3 5 7 5 8 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 5 7 7 8 f f f     A p p l e A c c o u n t   a r m v 6     < 0 e f 3 f 6 5 6 4 4 1 4 f 3 e f 0 3 0 0 3 1 a e 2 5 b 2 8 b b d >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / P r i v a t e F r a m e w o r k s / A p p l e A c c o u n t . f r a m e w o r k / A p p l e A c c o u n t 
0 x 3 5 8 1 5 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 5 8 1 a f f f     A s s e t s L i b r a r y S e r v i c e s   a r m v 6     < 2 2 4 b 3 c f 9 9 2 a 0 1 8 1 4 f 9 1 4 8 1 2 4 4 e 3 2 1 3 e b >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / P r i v a t e F r a m e w o r k s / A s s e t s L i b r a r y S e r v i c e s . f r a m e w o r k / A s s e t s L i b r a r y S e r v i c e s 
0 x 3 5 8 1 b 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 5 8 7 7 f f f     l i b G L I m a g e . d y l i b   a r m v 6     < 7 c 1 0 4 9 f 2 0 c 4 e 6 4 5 9 1 c 0 9 d 3 a c 0 0 c 7 d 3 a b >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / F r a m e w o r k s / O p e n G L E S . f r a m e w o r k / l i b G L I m a g e . d y l i b 
0 x 3 5 8 b c 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 5 8 c 3 f f f     l i b l o c k d o w n . d y l i b   a r m v 6     < f 4 7 0 d e a 1 8 0 d d f 2 3 8 8 6 d f 7 5 e b 2 5 6 d 3 8 8 8 >   / u s r / l i b / l i b l o c k d o w n . d y l i b 
0 x 3 5 8 c c 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 5 8 c f f f f     l i b g c c _ s . 1 . d y l i b   a r m v 6     < b e d 9 5 e d 1 8 7 3 5 0 c e 2 7 d 2 2 e d 2 4 1 e f 8 9 2 e a >   / u s r / l i b / l i b g c c _ s . 1 . d y l i b 
0 x 3 5 8 d 3 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 5 d 4 f f f f     U I K i t   a r m v 6     < 1 4 e c 6 c 9 2 6 b 8 b d a 7 1 b 7 3 1 3 6 f 6 e 1 a 6 a c 1 b >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / F r a m e w o r k s / U I K i t . f r a m e w o r k / U I K i t 
0 x 3 5 d 5 a 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 5 e 9 8 f f f     l i b S y s t e m . B . d y l i b   a r m v 6     < 7 0 5 7 1 c 1 e 6 9 7 e 2 a e 7 f 7 a 9 b 1 a 4 9 9 4 5 3 b b 6 >   / u s r / l i b / l i b S y s t e m . B . d y l i b 
0 x 3 5 f 7 e 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 5 f c 2 f f f     V i d e o T o o l b o x   a r m v 6     < 1 0 1 d b b c d 3 4 c c 3 2 3 1 a 8 b e 3 f d 6 3 9 2 5 5 6 a a >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / P r i v a t e F r a m e w o r k s / V i d e o T o o l b o x . f r a m e w o r k / V i d e o T o o l b o x 
0 x 3 5 f d b 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 6 1 6 2 f f f     C o r e G r a p h i c s   a r m v 6     < 9 a 1 d 7 2 f a 9 5 4 9 d 8 3 a b c 1 e 7 3 5 b a 3 7 a 4 d c 2 >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / F r a m e w o r k s / C o r e G r a p h i c s . f r a m e w o r k / C o r e G r a p h i c s 
0 x 3 6 1 6 7 0 0 0   -   0 x 3 6 1 7 8 f f f     D a t a A c c e s s E x p r e s s   a r m v 6     < c 1 1 2 b d 2 7 9 1 e b 7 0 6 5 2 6 d b 2 5 4 0 7 e c 1 1 7 d 4 >   / S y s t e m / L i b r a r y / P r i v a t e F r a m e w o r k s / D a t a A c c e s s E x p r e s s . f r a m e w o r k / D a t a A c c e s s E x p r e s s
```

What I'd like to know is why this is only happening for this app, and not any others, and how to fix it so they are symbolicated correctly ?

Any suggestions more than welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this happened to me, it was only logs I received via email.  If I recall, at least some were in a .msg file and I had to pick them out.  It may have been an Exchange encoding change.

If you show invisible characters, you will probably see something between each character.  You could find and replace to remove them or change the encoding in your editor.

Comment: That actually sounds like it might make sense. Its not happened for a while now, but if it does I'll certainly check that out.

Answer (score 1):

looks like wrong text encoding--you are reading a UTF-16 file as UTF-8.. try choosing the encoding explicitly in your text editor.

Answer (score 1):

How are you processing the crash logs? Aside from the above suggestion for file encoding (which merits investigation), there is always the brute force method of calling `atos` yourself. We sometimes do the this if we're only interested in a couple of calls.

1. Place both the MyApp.app and MyApp.dSYM file in the same directory somewhere (you can get this from your Archives section, "Show in Finder", then "Expand Package Contents". Just copy both out to a temp directory.
2. Take note of an address you want to see, then execute something like: `atos -arch armv6 -o MyApp.app/MyApp 0x000628b8`